# Jquery, how to get cookies plugin to remember current class on anchor tag

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I currently have the jquery code below that was refined by [RJD22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255920/rjd22)

```
$('.textResizing ul a').click(function(){
    $('.textResizing ul a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

I am using the Jquery Cookies Plugin and I would like to know how I can get cookies to remember the current class state after refresh.

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at this page: [Setting cookies with jQuery](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

As far as I can see you can set whole objects in a cookie so you can read it out again after refresh and set that class to the element you want.

This would look somewhat like this:

```
$.cookie("myState", { 'myClassToRemember' : 'current', 'myOtherThingToRemember' : 'someothervalue' });
```

After the refresh you do something like:

```
var state = $.cookie("myState");
$('.textResizing ul a').addClass(state.myClassToRemember);
```

Comment: $.cookie("myState", { 'myClassToRemember' : 'current' });
 
 var state = $.cookie("myState");
 $('.textResizing ul a').addClass(state.myClassToRemember);

Comment: I place an alert or something in the place where this code is executed, do you get the alert when you run it? And...if you look in the source code, is the class actually applied? Is the value being returned from the cookie as expected?

Comment: yeah cookies doesn't rememeber the class

Comment: Does it remember anything at all? I mean, if you simplify it all...can you retrieve a value from the cookie in the first place? Maybe it has something to do with your browser settings or something like that.

Comment: I am using the jquery font resizer plugin, cookies remembers the font size on refresh

Comment: Seems to work fine over  here...if I refresh or close my browser and visit again, the fonts are still big.

Comment: yeah that works but the current class doesn't stay on the  AAA nav item, how could I get this to work?

Comment: Does it work if you create a simple test file using jquery? I mean...if you create a simple HTML file with one element and try to add a class to that, which is coming from a cookie..does that work, based on the code we discussed earlier?

Comment: And if you simplify it more...just setting a string in the cookie and getting it afterwards? Like the example on the website I gave you earlier? Does that work?

Comment: hmm no, how would I adapt that to my code as I thin I did it wrong

Comment: I think you need to make a simple example for yourself and in that file just set a cookie like $.cookie("test", "mytestvalue") and getting it by alerting it on click or something like alert($.cookie("test")). If that even doesn't work...something else (jquery version?) must be wrong.

Comment: Aha, i fixed it, it is something to do with the fontsizer defaults.

Comment: Great! after all nothing to do with the cookies :)

Comment: Doh! I need this solutionion again :)

Comment: I thought you said you fixed it?